# MyEclipse not supporting J2EE 7 libraries such as Websocket

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ide, websocket, myeclipse

I am not able to add J2EE 7 libraries to my project in MyEclipse 10 while creating a new project .I want to use websocket api that is available with J2EE 7 in MyEclipse 10 .Is there any way to add those libraries and get content assist features for them

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can get content assist but you can use User Libraries to create your own library definition containing all the J2EE 7 jar files that you need. Remove the j2EE6 library from your build path and add your J2EE7 user library.  You would have to alter the deployment policies for the project, or get it to use the Deployment Assembly to avoid the J2EE7 user library from being deployed (assuming the server you're using has the needed libraries).

If this doesn't help, try asking on the [MyEclipse forums](http://myeclipseide.com/forums).

Comment: I found out that j2EE 7 apis are not yet supported on major application servers such as tomcat and jboss. Thus it is of no use to add these libraries to the project. Thanks for the suggestion